# Access JavaScript Variable values (Page URLs after clicks ) in JSP

Tags: javascript, java, ajax, jsp

I want to pass a javascript variable to my JSP and servlet, where I need to use it.
I have below Javscript to capture URL after hitting hyperlink of a JSP page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

 $("body").delegate("a", "click", function (event) {
        var url = $(this).attr('href');

       event.preventDefault();
        alert("URL IS===> "+url);
    });

</script>
```

I wanted to use js variable **url** in same JSP , i tried below jsp code but isn't working  :

```
<% String jsurl="<script>document.writeln(url);</script>"; 
out.println("jsurl >>>>>>"+jsurl);%>
```

I've spent many hours, trying to figure out how I can access a javascript variable in sampe jsp, but I haven't found any solution. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your JSP code will run before the javascript code is evaluated. So what you are trying to achieve will never work.

Comment: "how I can access a javascript variable in sampe jsp". The answer is via an ajax request. JSP runs on the server, javascript runs in the browser. Differnet environments, different languages, different times and places that the code is executed. You can use JSP to generate Javascript which is sent to the browser (and you can insert variable values into it which will effectively be static values in the resulting JS), but you can't do it like that the other way round. if you want to send something back to the server for processing, you have to make a new HTTP request, via ajax or postback.

Comment: I suggest you clarify your understanding of the lifecycle of a web page.